# How to extend a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python

I have run into some problems to extend numpy.ndarry,Is there some ways like the list's extend()?for example:given two arrays ,`a=array([1,2,3]),b=array([4])`,
want `c=array([1,2,3,4])`

Comment: That's not what `list.extend` does, you're creating a new array here. Google `numpy.concatenate`

Comment: yes, np.concatenate and np.hstack can both do this,thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

or you can use hstack. for example

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4])
c = np.hstack([a,b])
```

Answer (score 2):

There're three equivalent ways:

```
np.concatenate((a,b))
np.hstack((a,b))
np.r_[a,b]
```

The latter being most cryptic: it abuses the square brackets operator in order to get the most compact representation form.